# AngularJS reading array length

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom filter which is applied to an ng-repeat region, and for some reason items.length is returning as undefined.  Strangely, everything still works as expected though.  Is there a proper way to read the array length?

```
app.filter("myfilter", function() {
  return function(items, obj) {

        // Defined variables here - omitted from the example

        var arrayToReturn = [];
        for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
             // Code here - omitted from the example
        }

        return arrayToReturn;
  };
});
```

NG-REPEAT

```
<div ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | myfilter:{from:xyz} | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit" data-name="{{data.customerName}}" ng-click="eventHandler(data, $event)">
```

Comment: aside: that's a heck of a lot of directives, does that slow things down?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you returning a function within a function?  I'm wondering if 'items' is losing scope because of this.

Comment: No it doesn't slow it at all. It's only things like pagination and sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you determining that undefined value from a console error or a breakpoint? In this case the value is being filtered before being populated and causing it to error.

You could do something like

```
app.filter("myfilter", function() {
  return function(items, obj) {

    // Defined variables here - omitted from the example

    var arrayToReturn = [];

    if(items.length) {
        for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
             // Code here - omitted from the example
        }
    }


    return arrayToReturn;
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I varied this slight and now it's working.  if(typeof input !== 'undefined'){}

Answer (score -1):

Your filter doesn't get the right arguments. I suspect your `{from:xyz}` isn't really working.